# Regular expression to replace decimal followed by space and character

Tags: regex, string, text, full-text-search

I have a large file with following pattern that I need to find and replace:

> f1 f2 0.989 f2 f3 0.878 f3 f4 0.9977 and so on

I need to create a file like this:

> f1 f2 0.989,f2 f3 0.878,f3 f4 0.9977, and so on

That means I need to find string: decimal followed by space and then fx and replace it with decimal,fx. What would be regexp to find AND replace this expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
find: ( [\d.]+) (?=f\d)
replace: $1,
```

Comment: Trying on this website: http://25yearsofprogramming.com/javascript/regexp-text-editor.htm. Can't replace with either of the expressions

Comment: Are you sure this would work? Doesn't seems to be working for me.

Comment: Ok I will try again and report back.Thanks for trying.

Comment: Don't forget to check the global checkbox

Comment: Got it.Thanks a lot.Saved lot of time for me :)